# How can I get my animation to play while moving forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two animations, idle and jump. I want the jump animation to play at the same time as when the cube moves so it looks like it is moving up and forward but right now I can't get them to play together. Here is my code so far.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private Vector3 newPos;
    public Animator animator;

    void Start(){
         animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update(){

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        newPos = Vector3.forward + transform.position;
        animator.SetBool ("jump", true);
        transform.position =  (newPos);
    } else {
        animator.SetBool ("jump", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what this code does?and I can only see one animation it called "jump" where is the other one?

Comment: The idle one keeps playing until jump becomes true and then jump is supposed to play

Comment: and it doesn't start playing?

Comment: It does jump up it just doesn't move forward

Answer (score 0):

The new position must be applied to the actual position :

`transform.position = transform.position + (newPos);`